# How can I order query results by which field matched in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I've created a search field that will search posts for a term in the title or description, and returns a list of all posts that match.

```
def search(request):
    term = request.GET.get('q')
    posts = models.Post.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=term) | Q(description__icontains=term)
    )
    return render(request, 'posts/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

This works, but I'd like to order the results so that posts with titles that contain the search term show up first, followed by those where titles do not contain the search term but the description does.

I tried creating two queries and `union`ing them like so:

```
good_matches = models.Post.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=term))
just_ok_matches = models.Post.objects.filter(
        ~Q(title__icontains=term) & Q(description__icontains=term)
    )
posts = good_matches | just_ok_matches
```

But the order seems to be unchanged from the first example.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1435208/4338498) seems to cover how to do this with raw SQL, by creating a scoring system. Perhaps there's a way to implement this with Django's ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django prepares and then does one query to db, but you can call force by convert queryset to list, for example:

```
good_matches = models.Post.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=term))
just_ok_matches = models.Post.objects.filter(
        ~Q(title__icontains=term) & Q(description__icontains=term)
    )
posts = list(good_matches) + list(just_ok_matches)
```

Comment: OK yeah I figured query sets being lazy was the issue. This works - thanks!